# SQL Server 2012 - Number sequence (1-12) and ensuring that 15 = 3 months

Tags: sql-server

I am creating an SQL database for Apartments with 2 tables, Apartments and Tenants. My create code is as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE Apartments
(
    ApartmentID smallint PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
    Occupied smallint NOT NULL default Occupied,
    Rent Money default 0,
    CurrentOccupier smallint NOT NULL Unique,
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Tenant
(
    TenantID smallint PRIMARY KEY,
    TenantName varchar (20),
    DurationofLease smallint default 12 NOT NULL,
)
```

The duration of the lease in table Tenant cannot be blank and has a default value of 12. My issue is that some of the data I have to input, the duration if the lease is greater than 12, ie it is 18 months. So how do I include a condition on the column, where 18 months is equal to 6 months. Essentially my column should have only 1 to 12 numbers, so if the data says 26 months, that would automatically equal 2 months.

```
INSERT INTO Tenant (TenantID, TenantName, DurationofLease)
VALUES ('21', 'Frank Byrne', '15'), - This would = 3 months.
       ('11', 'Terence Griffith', '18'), - This would = 6 months
```

This may be an easy question, but I am new to SQL so all help would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone
Josie

Comment: Please format your code blocks appropriately http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want modular arithmetic:

```
select t.*, ((DurationOfLease - 1) % 12) + 1 as months
from tenant t;
```

Note:  do not enter numbers using single quotes.  It is misleading.

You can add this as a computed column into your table:

```
alter table tenant add months as (((DurationOfLease - 1) % 12) + 1);
```

Then you don't have to calculate it in a query.

Comment: This worked. Though adding it as a computed column is the best idea. So if I understand modulo operator correctly and the above formula, because 12 goes into 15 once with three as a remainder, that is why 15 months converts to three months likewise 12 into 18, goes once with six as remainder, hence month 6? Would I be correct in my understanding?

Comment: Apologies, I have to try and understand one other thing. When you write select t.* and from tenant t - what does the t refer to? Thanks

Comment: @Josie . . . Your reasoning on the modulo operator seems correct.  The `t` is a table alias and an important part of the SQL language.

Comment: @Gordon.....I did think about the alias, but being new I do not want to presume. Thanks a million, this has really helped. This was my first question to this site, I am so impressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **modulo operator** to limit the duration to a specific value, like 12.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279(v=sql.120).aspx) reads as follows:

> **Syntax**
>
> `dividend % divisor`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - *dividend*
>
>   Is the numeric expression to divide. *dividend* must be a valid expression of any one of the data types in the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data type. divisor Is the numeric expression by which to divide the dividend.
> - *divisor*
>
>   must be any valid expression of any one of the data types in the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data type.
>
> **Result Types**
>
> Determined by data types of the two arguments.

As you don't want to have zero values you have subtract 1 before and add 1 after the modulo:

`((duration - 1) % 12) + 1` will return

- 9 for duration = 9
- 12 for duration = 12
- 3 for duration = 15
- 6 for duration = 18
- ...

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. I read up some more on the modulo operator, thanks to your comment and now I understand it and how the formula in the above comment works in SQL.